# Single Element Voltage Reducer

Tags: voltage-controlled-resistor

Im building a project that does not involve any transformer.
[image: 1]

Without using any transformer, what elements or components (in the question mark above) can you use that can reduce the voltage from say 120V to 85V after it?

Comment: If it was DC, you could do it with a zener, but with AC, you don't have any easy options. Anyway, what you need is rather unusual and smells like a design flaw. What current do you need to draw there? Do you need the output to be also AC, or DC?

Comment: A polypropylene (400v) capacitor can be used. However, the value depends on the load resistance (and reactance) @85v. Research "capacitive reactance": \$X_C=\dfrac{1}{2\pi fC}\$

Comment: Without knowing the characteristics of the load it is impossible to answer your question. Add more details.

Comment: The load is just a special 30 watt lamp. I just want a 85 volt ac output. Not dc. and want other options besides a transformer

Comment: You should edit the details of the load in the question, as the question is incomplete without it. Don't put it in the comments. Also, why are you set on not using a transformer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you:

1. Know your load characteristics and these remain relatively constant.
2. You don’t care too much about load regulation, eg. 80V or 90v is the same to you.
3. You don’t care that removing the load puts through the whole 120V at the output.
4. Isolation is not important for the application.

Then any series element that has a voltage drop when an AC current flows through it will do the trick. Assuming you want to remain linear and not distort the AC waveform, then your obvious choices are a resistor, a capacitor, or an inductor. Any of them will create a voltage divider with your load.

A 30W load at 85V implies a real impedance (resistance) of 240ohm and a current of 350mA. So, to produce a drop of 35V all you need is an impedance of 100ohm.

- A 100ohm resistor will do it, but it will be dissipating 12W in the process.
- At 60Hz, a 265mH inductor would do it with no power dissipation.
- At 60Hz, a 26uF capacitor would do it, with no power dissipation.

There are many more options that involve other compromises, but it can’t get simpler than this.

---

But without a load (and a multimeter presents a load, a small one but a load nonetheless) the problem becomes physically impossible.

One of the lesser known laws of physics is the conservation of information. To achieve the desired goal the mystery material would need to break this law.

Let’s consider the DC case. In that case the solution is easy, place a battery or any other element that can maintain an electric field (e.g., a charged capacitor) and you obtain your desired result. So, what makes the AC case impossible? Why can’t we come up with an AC battery to solve the problem?

By making the problem AC, two new pieces of information are added that are not present in the DC case. The frequency and the phase. The mystery element knows nothing of either of those, unless it can access the other wire.

In the above I simply assumed the frequency as a given (and the resistor does not care), but this still leaves the phase as an unknown.  This information is only provided to the mystery element via the circulating current when the load is attached.

It is quite possible to design an “AC battery”, that maintains a stable voltage across its leads, but it would *need* a circulating current (a load) so that it can synchronize its frequency and phase to that of the source.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's the answer I'm seeking. But what if I'll just use a volt meter to measure the output. You said if one remove the load, the full 120v will be there. So what component must you use to produce voltage drop when just a voltmeter is used to measure the output?

Comment: @Jtl that’s not physically possible, unless you design it with the multimeter as the load.

Comment: But imagine the green rectangle in the illustration is insulator like rubber, then you won't measure any voltage in the output using a voltmeter so perhaps there are material where as you increase the conduction in the green rectangle, the voltage increases.. isn't this what semiconductor can do.. or other stuff?

Comment: @Jtl oh, and your insulator example ignored the fact that the voltmeter is a physical device and thus presents a load, which is the only thing that could make that voltage zero. If you could find an ideal multimeter you would see the whole 120 even after the insulator. A capacitor **is** a piece of insulator.

Comment: @Jtl I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 2):

> Without using any transformer, what elements or components (in the
>   question mark above) can you use that can reduce the voltage from say
>   120V to 85V after it?

There are none because the element has no knowledge of: -

1. The other supply line i.e. element "X" does not connect to it so it cannot determine that its own feed-line is 120 volts above some disconnected "other line"
2. Both load connections i.e. element "X" can know the current that is passing through it but it cannot know how to regulate its output voltage because it has no other connection to the "other" line.

Comment: Without producing exactly 85V ac output.  What components (or even fault condition) can make the voltage vary to any values?

Comment: @Jtl your comment is unclear. In my answer I've tried to explain that element X has no means for controlling the output voltage because it neither knows what the input voltage is nor can measure the output voltage so that it can stabilize it.